# how to create variables/const with {variableName}

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm watching some javascript videos and I've seen that some people create variables like this const {variable} = something.

```
    router.delete('/:movieId', async function(req,res, next){ //delete
        const {movieId} = req.params; //req.params 
        try {
            const deletedMovie = await moviesServices.deleteMovie({movieId});
            res.status(200).json({
                data: deletedMovie,
                message: 'movies deleted'
            });
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    })
}
```

and too i've seen that people used to do this when they declare a parameter in a function, example:

```
async updateMovie({movieId, movie} = {}){
    const updatedMovieId = await this.MongoDB.update(
        this.collection, 
        movieId, 
        movie
        );
    return updatedMovieId;
}
```

these are some of Nodejs,Express Api code that i've been using to study, i don't know nothing about this kind of declaring variables so i'd like to know when and what are they use for

Comment: a lot of the examples look like they use different libraries and modules, so that could be why. there are several ways to declare variables in pure js, and other ways like writing to json (such as the first example). I havent worked with too much node, so it would be appreciated if you could expand or ask more specifics.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your confusion is in the first example. This is called destructuring. 
Here's an example to explain.

```
const person = {  
    name: 'Luke',
    age: '24',
    facts: {
        hobby: 'Photo',
        work: 'Software Developer'
    }
}

const {name, age} = person;  
console.log(name, age); // 'Luke' '24'
```

The curly braces a syntax sugar to easily pull data from arrays and objects. The example is from this [great write up](https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-28-es6-destructuring-an-elegant-way-of-extracting-data-from-arrays-and-objects-in-javascript/).